# How to delete images from digital ocean with node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using multer to upload images in digital ocean in the 'upload' folder and store image path into mongodb. Now user can delete old images and can upload new ones,so my question is how i can delete same images from upload folder??

Answer (score 2):

```
## Hello you can use these code for delete file from digital ocean space ##
import AWS from "aws-sdk" //import aws sdk 
//initialize digital ocean space, values are set using env file
const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(process.env.SPACES_ENDPOINT);
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: process.env.SPACES_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SPACES_SECRET
});
//set delete param bucket name and file name with extension
const param = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName
};
//call delete method 
s3.deleteObject(param, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err', err)

    }
    console.log('data', data)
});
```